# Complex Irrational Integration

Tags: indefinite-integrals

> Calculation of $$\int \frac{(x-1)\sqrt{x^4+2x^3-x^2+2x+1}}{x^2(x+1)}dx$$

Try: put $x=t^2$ and $dx = 2tdt$

Let $$I = 2\int\frac{(t^2-1)\sqrt{t^8+2t^6-t^4+2t^2+1}}{t(t^2+1)}dt$$

$$I = 2\int \frac{\bigg(1-\frac{1}{t^2}\bigg)\sqrt{t^8+2t^6-t^4+2t^2+1}}{(t+\frac{1}{t})}dt$$

could some help me to solve it , Thanks

Comment: This leads to an elliptic integral

Comment: Just out of curiosity : why did you try $x=t^2$ ? I do not see the reason.

Comment: I am trying to convert it into $(t+\frac{1}{t})$ form but in suceed

Answer (score 2):

Note first that $x^4+2x^3-x^2+2x+1$ has symmetric coefficients, so it can be expressed in terms of $(x+1/x)$. In particular, 
$$
\begin{align}
x^4+2x^3-x^2+2x+1 &= x^2\left(\left(x+\frac 1x\right)^2+2\left(x+\frac 1x\right)-3\right)
\end{align}
$$
Bearing this in mind, we use $u = x + \frac 1x$, then $du = 1 - \frac{1}{x^2} dx$. Now,
\begin{align}
\int \frac{(x-1)\sqrt{x^4+2x^3-x^2+2x+1}}{x^2(x+1)}\,dx&=\int \frac{(x-1)\sqrt{u^2+2u-3}}{x(x+1)}\,dx\\
&=\int \frac{(x^2-1)\sqrt{u^2+2u-3}}{x(x+1)^2}\,dx\\
&=\int \frac{x(1-\frac{1}{x^2})\sqrt{u^2+2u-3}}{(x+1)^2}\,dx\\
&=\int \frac{x\sqrt{u^2+2u-3}}{(x+1)^2}\,du\\
&=\int \frac{\sqrt{u^2+2u-3}}{x+2+\frac 1x}\,du\\
&=\int \frac{\sqrt{u^2+2u-3}}{u+2}\,du.
\end{align}
This is now a much more routine integral ([Wolfram Alpha manages](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20(sqrt(u%5E2%2B2u-3))%2F(u%2B2)%20du)), which I leave to you.